# Custom iOS push notification sound

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have been facing an issue. I implemented push notification in iOS with custom sound. Its a MP3 file. It plays well when I receive a push notification in iOS 5, but in iOS4, it doesn't play any sound.
Can you help me with this?

The code is like this

```
{
    "aps": {
        "badge": 10,
        "alert": "Hello",
        "sound": "sound.mp3"
    }
}
```

Nithin

Comment: could you add a little bit of code to this question to show *how* you set the custom sound for your push notifications?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the push notification guide:

> You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Then, in
>   Xcode, add the sound file to your project as a nonlocalized resource
>   of the application bundle.

It doesn't say anything about MP3s. I've used aif files which worked. I'd stick to what [Apple specifies](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsound).

Comment: I tried to add a wav file, but it doesn't work even in iOS 5. So where is the problem? Did custom audio work in iOS4 too? And in iPad too?

Comment: I tried it once but the audio file wasn't being bundled in with the app. Make sure that the file is included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase.

Comment: Yes..because in iOS 5 it works. It worked for you in iOS 4 too and iPad?

Comment: It should work on iOS 4 as well. I saw your other post where you say you dont hear any sound. If the sound file is wrong or can't play for any reason, the system should play the default sound. This might sound pretty obvious but do you have the sound option available under notification settings in the settings app?

Comment: My question is it playing my packed sound when I got push and the app is closed?

Comment: I know that I shouldn't use .mp3 file, as Apple didn't mention it in Push document. So, I converted my file into .wav file using FFMpeg, and it didn't work. I don't know which are the arguments needed of a wav file (while converting )so that it can be attached to APN payload. I tried: "ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -ar 8000 -ac 1 out.wav" and "ffmpeg -i in.mp3 out.wav", both didn't help.

Comment: Hi there, I noticed that wav file that can play for push has sample rate = 44100, and bits per sample = 16. So I used this command line `ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 out.wav`, then the output could be used for push. If you use this command and your file still cannot play --> maybe something goes wrong with the input file --> let's try another.

Comment: That link is broken.

Answer (score 6):

You can't play .mp3-files. However, you can convert them into .wav files here: http://media.io/ (online & free). Then put the converted file in your XCode project and you can call it by specifying `"sound":"sound.wav"`